# Json no trae todo los resultados

Tags: java, android, json

buenos días estoy realizando una aplicación con Android Studio  3.0.1  con una base de datos **mysql** y al momento de realizar la consulta me devuelve un **json** y al momento de que llega a la app me regresa

> ["2","Ejemplo2","Autor2","Editorial2","Facultad2","0"]["7","Ejemplo2","Autor4","Editorial4","Facultad5","0"]

el response pero al momento de  pasarlo a un **JSONArray** solo me  da el primer partde  del resultado

> ["2","Ejemplo2","Autor2","Editorial2","Facultad2","0"]

pero no se cual es el error por que no me brinda el resultado como lo deseo soy nuevo programando y si me puede indicar que estoy haciendo mal  o en donde o como buscar informacion estare agradecido  anexo mi código

```js
    private void ConsultaTitulo(String URL) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest =  new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    String a;
                    Log.d("Json responda",response);
                    ja = new JSONArray(response);
                    String contra = ja.getString(0);
                    Log.d("Json responda",response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("Json responda",  String.valueOf(jsonObj.get("id")));

                    }

                  //  Log.d("Json responda",contra);

                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override

            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

**Error**

> 04-11 05:34:48.826 4349-4349/com.example.ferney.bibliotecacur D/Json responda:
>                                                                                  ["2","Ejemplo2","Autor2","Editorial2","Facultad2","0"]["7","Ejemplo2","Autor4","Editorial4","Facultad5","0"]
>   04-11 05:34:48.826 4349-4349/com.example.ferney.bibliotecacur D/Json responda:
>                                                                                  ["2","Ejemplo2","Autor2","Editorial2","Facultad2","0"]["7","Ejemplo2","Autor4","Editorial4","Facultad5","0"]
>   04-11 05:34:48.870 4349-4349/com.example.ferney.bibliotecacur W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value 2 at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
>   04-11 05:34:48.872 4349-4349/com.example.ferney.bibliotecacur W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
>   04-11 05:34:48.872 4349-4349/com.example.ferney.bibliotecacur W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:525)

Comment: Cual es el valor de response ? es importante agregues exactamente como se obtiene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error indica que tratas de convertir información a `JSONObject`, pero esta información no tiene la estructura de un objeto Json.

> org.json.JSONException: Value 2 at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot
>   be converted to JSONObject

Recuerda que la respuesta .Json puede ser de dos tipos:

> **- Si el .json inicia con `{` se considera como objeto Json.**
>
> **- Si el .json inicia con `[` es considerado como Arreglo Json.**

En el caso que comentas, si recibes esto como respuesta:

```
["2","Ejemplo2","Autor2","Editorial2","Facultad2","0"]["7","Ejemplo2","Autor4","Editorial4","Facultad5","0"]
```

solo se obtendría un valor como JSON Array que sería el primero:

```
["2","Ejemplo2","Autor2","Editorial2","Facultad2","0"]
```

ahora con respecto al error, en realidad no hay un elemento que se considere objeto JSON, este elemento debería estar definido por los contenedores `{` y `}`, por esta razón cuando tratas de convertir a `JSONObject` se genera el error `JSONException` .

Incluso tratas de llamar un key llamado `id` del objeto pero no tienes definidos `keys`

```
jsonObj.get("id")
```

---

Considera cambiar la estructura de tu respuesta json como ejemplo, un array con objetos y cada objeto tiene keys y su respectivo valor:

```
[{
    "id": "2",
    "nombre": "Ejemplo2",
    "autor": "Autor2",
    "editorial": "Editorial2",
    "facultad": "Facultad2",
    "valor": "0"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "nombre": "Ejemplo2",
    "autor": "Autor4",
    "editorial": "Editorial4",
    "facultad": "Facultad5",
    "valor": "0"
}]
```

Comment: excelente respuesta , http://jsoneditoronline.org/ te dejo este formateador por si necesitas validar si el json es un json valido

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag gracias por la herramienta me fue muy util